# Trouble Using TailwindCSS with Next.js and Multiple Pages Without _app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Hey I'm new to nextjs and I can't seem to figure this out. I didn't want to use _app.js because I want different pages eg. (/about, /forum, etc). From what it looks like _app.js wraps all content into one page. I'm stuck here because I want to use tailwindcss however it won't work inside the module.css and I can't import a .css file if I don't have an _app.js it has to be a module.css

Any solutions to this?

Comment: Show the code for styles.css and the code for module.css, follow these instructions https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: There is no code other than the tailwind imports. I'm asking a general question I don't have an error.

Comment: You described a lot of changes in your code, being a issue with no errors it is even harder to guess your issue without any reproducible steps or code. You can try stackblitz and share a sample of your codebase so people can see what you are trying to do.